# How to add a response to a button with Gtkmm

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I am trying to add a response to a button in a Gtk::Dialog but I don't know why it does not work I try to type this :

```
button_quit(Gtk::Stock::QUIT, Gtk::RESPONSE_CLOSE)
```

but it does not work. Also, I tried to do with an other way like this :

```
button_quit.signal_clicked().connect([]() {Gtk::Main::quit();});
```

but when I clicked on the button I have this error :

```
(code:7199): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_main_quit: assertion 'main_loops != NULL' failed
```

So  if you know how to solve this it will be very helpful for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [add_button](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Dialog.html#aca037e133ab2a91c646f23b7b17afb9b).

```
Gtk::Dialog dialog;
auto button = dialog.add_button("Ok", Gtk::RESPONSE_CLOSE);
dialog.signal_response().connect([&](int response_id)
{
    std::cout<<response_id<<std::endl;
});
```